# Identify if a product was purchased before or not and get all records for the requested purchase date not just if there is a new product purchased

Tags: sql

When I run my report, I want to be able to identify if a certain product was purchased before or not, if it was then have a 'N' in the new column "New_Purchase' if it is then 'Y'.  Attached is an image of the table and below it are my desired results Below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQYj6.png)

Comment: Please add the dbms and your query (not as picture). So is your query looking only at 9/26/2022? Is the date part of the query? SHould we assume you are querying today's date and then looking backwards for prior purchases?

Comment: Yes my query only wants the purchases on 9/26/22 and yes looking to see if the item was purchased prior to 9/26/22.  If it was purchased before 9/26/22 then I want to add an ‘N’ in the New_Purchase column, if not then have a ‘Y’

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp1
FROM tableA
where Dates = '2022-09-26'

  
SELECT t1.Customer_ID,
       t1.Customer_Name,
       t1.Dates,
       t2.Product,
       CASE WHEN MIN(t2.Dates) < t1.Dates THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as 'New Purchase'
FROM #temp1 t1
JOIN tableA t2 on t1.Customer_ID = t2.Customer_ID
group by t1.Customer_ID, t1.Customer_Name,t2.Product, T1.Dates
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PNafXcw0)